# Calculating pi with recursion in java

Tags: java

I'm working on a method that is supposed to utilize recursion to calculate pi. The problem, however is that in order to get close the input number (num) needs to be very very high. Inputting 5000 as seen below got me to 3.141392653591791. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

This is the equation I'm working from and am required to use:
[image]

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class PiSeries {
    public static double calculatePi(double num) {
        if(num == 1) {
            return 4;
        } else {
            return (4*((Math.pow(-1,num+1))/((2*num)-1)) + calculatePi(num-1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calculatePi(5000));
    }
}
```

Comment: probably you are using a function that converge to PI very slowly, and so it needs a lot of iterations in order to be very close to it

Comment: Wow. I get that this is probably for an assignment. And I understand you probably need `Math.pow` for your algorithm but Java ***gives*** you [`Math.PI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI) so that it's totally unnecessary to determine it yourself. Also, I feel like `3` is probably a better approximation to PI than 4.

Comment: You don't need to call Math.pow(). Just test the parity of num. And num should be typed as an int.

Comment: I wonder what `k` is in that formula, given that the ∑ iterator variable is named `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The series you are using is called [The Gregory–Leibniz series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80).

> Leibniz's formula converges extremely slowly: it exhibits sublinear convergence. Calculating π to 10 correct decimal places using direct summation of the series requires about five billion terms.

See also a nice [graphical comparison of convergence of a few historical series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_pi_infinite_series.svg)

Answer (score 1):

The posted equation is probably not correct - check initial value. Implemented code is not posted equation (stopping at `num == 1`), but seems mathematically correct (to calculate PI).

`5000` elements -> error about `1 / (2*5000-1) = 1/10000` that is, forth decimal digit